# execute cpp code written with visual studio on the Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, opencv, cross-compilation, c++

I am new to the Raspberry Pi and opencv lib, I have spent some time learning opencv up until I finished my first program written in c++ .

Now I want to compile and execute the same c++ file on the Pi , but I get errors, mostly "undefined references". I know I installed Opencv correctly because I have run some of the sample codes successfully.

My question is. Can I simply copy the code I have written on the Pi and execute it there? Or what else do I need to do before to make that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try using cmake. From OpenCV's website, it is recommended that you use cmake to compile it. Refer to http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html

Comment: One sentence plus a link does not count as an answer, you need to give a thorough explanation as to why your solution works. As well as different ways of approaching the problem, one solution does not work for all.

Comment: it actually helped , i tought i would do a whole linkage process all over again , thank you very much